# Efficient PairRDD operations on DataFrame with Spark SQL GROUP BY

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

This question is about the duality between `DataFrame` and `RDD` when it comes to aggregation operations. In Spark SQL one can use table generating UDFs for custom aggregations but creating one of those is typically noticeably less user-friendly than using the aggregation functions available for RDDs, especially if table output is not required.

Is there an efficient way to apply pair RDD operations such as `aggregateByKey` to a DataFrame which has been grouped using GROUP BY or ordered using ORDERED BY?

Normally, one would need an explicit `map` step to create key-value tuples, e.g., `dataFrame.rdd.map(row => (row.getString(row.fieldIndex("category")), row).aggregateByKey(...)`. Can this be avoided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really. While `DataFrames` can be converted to `RDDs` and vice versa this is relatively complex operation and methods like `DataFrame.groupBy` don't have the same semantics as their counterparts on `RDD`.

The closest thing you can get is [a new `DataSet` API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35424854/1560062) introduced in Spark 1.6.0. It provides a much closer integration with `DataFrames` and  `GroupedDataset` class with its own set of methods including `reduce`, `cogroup` or `mapGroups`:

```
case class Record(id: Long, key: String, value: Double)

val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(
    (1L, "foo", 3.0), (2L, "bar", 5.6),
    (3L, "foo", -1.0), (4L, "bar", 10.0)
)).toDF("id", "key", "value")

val ds = df.as[Record]
ds.groupBy($"key").reduce((x, y) => if (x.id < y.id) x else y).show

// +-----+-----------+
// |   _1|         _2|
// +-----+-----------+
// |[bar]|[2,bar,5.6]|
// |[foo]|[1,foo,3.0]|
// +-----+-----------+
```

In some specific cases it is possible to leverage `Orderable` semantics to group and process data using `structs` or `arrays`. You'll find an example in [SPARK DataFrame: select the first row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33878370/1560062)

Comment: Yes, Datasets do look interesting but the support in Spark 1.6.0 is still quite buggy: they are an experimental feature.

Comment: It is :) Paradoxically Spark DataFrames play much nicer with PySpark than Scala. Unfortunately hops between JVM and Python make things quite expensive.

Comment: @zero323 , have been testing your example, but getting error `error: value reduce is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.RelationalGroupedDataset` . Am I missing an import? (only reduce I've managed to find are related to RDDs)